# Storing metadata in litedb database

Tags: c#, .net, litedb

I'm using separate litedb databases and want to add some additional information to each database. How to do that properly?

I'm going to use special collection with one single object with metadata:

```
internal class DBInfo {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string Source { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime DTCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

When creating a database:

```
_db = new LiteDatabase(dbPath);

var dbInfoCollection = _db.GetCollection<DBInfo>();
var dbInfo = new DBInfo();
dbInfo.Source = "company 1";
dbInfoCollection.Insert(dbInfo);
dbInfoCollection.Update(dbInfo);

_db.Commit();
```

To read metadata from an existing database:

```
_db = new LiteDatabase(dbPath);
var dbInfo = _db.GetCollection<DBInfo>().FindAll().Single();
Console.WriteLine($"Source of current database: {dbInfo.Source}");
```

It works, but doesn't look good. Maybe there is some more logical way to do this? For example, somehow to store the serialized string with metadata in database. But I didn't find suitable properties.

Comment: _"but doesn't look good"_ - what makes you say that?

Comment: @Dai Using a collection to store single object

Comment: That's how document dbs work, though.

Comment: @Fildor I understand that. The question is about best practices, maybe there is some other way how to do this particular task: storing metadata.